# Response from PHP

Tags: php, android

I have a problem which happens when my users register with mysql.
When a username and password are registered, the app must show the message "User created successfully".
But the app doesn't show any message and instead closes itself.

The username *has* been inserted into the database.
It gives me the same problem even when I send empty data.

This my PHP response

```
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);
```

This is my register Java code

```
        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

        // json success element
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {


            Log.d("Username Successfully Added!", json.toString());
            finish();
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat output so we can have more information relating to your error. I have a hunch but i want to see logcat first

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of

> finish()

in your code. Generally,

> finish()

destroy the Activity. That's why your app closed. Remove it and test it again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code could use a little bit of decoupling here using Events (Subscriber/Publish design pattern). I will give you some sort of idea or guideline so that you can give it a shot.

- My current favorite approach would be to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) - a simple well-tested android library that helps decouple your code (eliminates or simply reduces dependencies).
- After adding the library to your `build.gradle` file, you want to register for your activity to listen for a given event - EventBus will notify whoever is listening for notifications. You register for instance inside `onCreate()` method of your activity by calling `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` then remember to unregister inside onDestroy like this: `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)`
- Next thing would be to create a POJO class (Plain Old Java Object) like `LoginCompletedEvent` this should have whatever variables you need to pass back to your UI or whoever is listening for updates from a background operation like making HTTP requests.
- For now, if you are using an AsyncTask, inside `onPostExecute()` method, you can notify your activity whether login operation or registration was successful by doing the following: `EventBus.getDefault().post(new LoginCompletedEvent(true, message))`. This passes the response message to the subscriber so you can update the UI accordingly.
- Finally, inside your Activity or Fragment (Subscriber), you simply 
  add a method with the following signature to get notified and catch the data passed back:

  ```
  public void onEvent(LoginCompletedEvent event){ //do something with the feedback here}
  ```

That is all you need to accomplish your tasks using a clean Publisher/Subscriber design pattern which is provided to you by EventBus.

I hope this suggestion helps you. If you have any farther needs or clarification questions, let me know because I will be happy to help!